# Javascript error when grouping in Kendo Grid with AJAX

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a Kendo grid populated with AJAX in a ASP.NET MVC view, and when I try to group by the property FacturasCabecera.NFactura I get the Javascript error `d.ArtFacturasCabecera is undefined`, so the Kendo grid hangs. One of the elements of the model in the grid is FacturasCabecera, it is another model object that contains the property I want to group by. The code for the grid, which is in a Razor view, is:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Macromed.Models.ArtFacturasDetalleModels>()
    .Name("GridAuditoria")
    .Columns(
        columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(e => e.ArtFacturasCabecera.Nfactura).Title("Nro. Factura").Groupable(true);
            columns.Bound(e => e.ArtFacturasCabecera.FchFactura).Title("Fecha Factura").ClientTemplate("#= kendo.toString(kendo.parseDate(ArtFacturasCabecera.FchFactura), 'dd MMM yyyy') #").Groupable(false);
            columns.Bound(e => e.NItem).Title("Nro. Item").Groupable(false);
            columns.Bound(e => e.Codigo).Title("Código").Groupable(false);
            columns.Bound(e => e.ArtFacturasCabecera.FchPago).Title("Fecha pago").ClientTemplate("#= kendo.toString(kendo.parseDate(ArtFacturasCabecera.FchPago), 'dd MMM yyyy') #").Groupable(false);
            columns.Bound(e => e.ArtFacturasCabecera.FchVencimiento).Title("Fecha vencimiento").ClientTemplate("#= kendo.toString(kendo.parseDate(ArtFacturasCabecera.FchVencimiento), 'dd MMM yyyy') #").Groupable(false);
            columns.Bound(e => e.MontoFacturado).Title("Monto Facturado").ClientTemplate("#= kendo.toString(MontoFacturado,'c')#").Groupable(false);
            columns.Bound(e => e.AuditoriaDetalle.MontoTeorico).Title("Monto Teorico").ClientTemplate("#= kendo.toString(AuditoriaDetalle.MontoTeorico,'c')#").Groupable(false);
            columns.Bound(e => e.IdTraslado).Title("").ClientTemplate(@Html.ActionLink("Ajustar traslado", "AjustarTraslado",
            new { id = "#=IdTraslado#", idFactura = "#=IdFactura#", NItem = "#=NItem#", fechadesde = ViewBag.fechadesde, fechahasta = ViewBag.fechahasta }).ToHtmlString());
        })
    .Groupable(group => group.Enabled(true).Messages(mm => mm.Empty("Arrastre un Encabezado de Columna y Colóquela aquí para Agrupar")))
    .DataSource(
        datasource => datasource.Ajax()
                .PageSize(10)
                .Read(read => read.Action("GetFacturaAjustar", "AuditoriaTraslados", new { id = ViewBag.id, fechadesde = ViewBag.fechadesde, fechahasta = ViewBag.fechahasta }))
                .Model(model =>
                {
                    model.Id(p => p.IdFactura);
                    model.Field(p => p.ArtFacturasCabecera.FchFactura);
                }))
)
```

And this is the code that fetches the data from the database is the following:

```
IQueryable<ArtFacturasDetalleModels> objfactura = from facturadet in db.ArtFacturasDetalle
  from facturacab in db.ArtFacturasCabecera
  from auditoriadet in db.AuditoriaDetalle
  from itemauditoria in db.AuditoriaDetalleItems
  where facturacab.IdFactura == facturadet.IdFactura
  && facturacab.IdFactura == auditoriadet.IdFactura &&
  facturacab.IdFactura == itemauditoria.IdFactura &&
  auditoriadet.IdAuditoria == itemauditoria.IdAuditoria &&
  facturadet.NItem == itemauditoria.NItem
  && facturacab.IdPrestador == id &&
  auditoriadet.Auditado == "S" && auditoriadet.Ajustar == "S" &&
  itemauditoria.ItemAuditado == true && itemauditoria.AjustarItem == true
  select new ArtFacturasDetalleModels
  {
      IdFactura = facturadet.IdFactura,
      NItem = facturadet.NItem,
      Codigo = facturadet.Codigo,
      MontoFacturado = facturadet.MontoFacturado,
      IdTraslado = facturadet.IdTraslado,
      ArtFacturasCabecera = new ArtFacturasCabeceraModels
      {
          IdPrestador = facturacab.IdPrestador,
          FchFactura = (DateTime)facturacab.FchFactura,
          FchPago = facturacab.FchPago,
          FchVencimiento = facturacab.FchVencimiento,
          Nfactura = facturacab.Nfactura
      },
      AuditoriaDetalle = new AuditoriaDetalleModels
      {
          IdAuditoria = auditoriadet.IdAuditoria,
          IdFactura = facturadet.IdFactura,
          MontoTeorico = auditoriadet.MontoTeorico
      }
  };
DataSourceResult result1 = objfactura.ToDataSourceResult(request1);
return Json(result1);
```

I suspect the Kendo grid can't deal with this kind of model properly...

Comment: Is there any way you can pare down the code to *just* what's relevant?

Comment: I pared down some of the code, but I still kept most of it so you can see how the model is structured.

Comment: `ToDataSourceResult()` will execute the group query, check `result1` and see if the models have been created correctly.

Comment: ToDataSourceResult creates the model correctly.

Comment: have you tried simplified your model without nested object inside it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making a new model without nesting fixed the issue. I guess Kendo grids don't work with nested models.